# NEST.JS app deployment fails on start:prod digital ocean

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, digital-ocean, nest

I have a nest.js app Im trying to get to work on the APP platform, I have installed the app from GIThub the output is saying its working ok but DO fails the deployment

My Output:

```
[2023-02-08 17:27:15] > node dist/src/main
[2023-02-08 17:27:15] 
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +69ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseCoreModule dependencies initialized +235ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +16ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] UsersModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] KpiModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] HolidaysModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +7ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +3ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] UsersController {/users}: +0ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/users, GET} route +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/users/:username, GET} route +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/signup, POST} route +2ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] KpiController {/kpi}: +0ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/kpi/kpis/:userID, GET} route +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/kpi/kpi, POST} route +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/auth}: +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/auth/login, POST} route +2ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] HolidaysController {/holidays}: +1ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/holidays/holidays/:userID, GET} route +0ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/holidays/holiday, POST} route +3ms
[2023-02-08 17:27:18] [Nest] 17  - 02/08/2023, 5:27:18 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +5ms
[]
```

As you can see Nest has started up fine

My App Spec

```
alerts:
- rule: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
- rule: DOMAIN_FAILED
name: vmosbackend
region: lon
services:
- build_command: npm run build
  environment_slug: node-js
  github:
    branch: master
    deploy_on_push: true
    repo: VST-GLOBAL/vstkpibackend
  http_port: 8080
  instance_count: 1
  instance_size_slug: basic-xxs
  name: vstkpibackend
  routes:
  - path: /
  run_command: npm run start:prod
  source_dir: /
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What errors are you getting? And what port are you using for your nestjs app?

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the wrong port! changed it to 3000 and its working

Answer (score 1):

Updating the port to 3000 worked and allowed the app to deploy

so

```
  http_port: 8080
```

to

```
  http_port: 3000
```